# Airflow: How to create Dynamic SubDags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow, airflow-scheduler

This is not my exact circumstance, but it does explain the circumstances of my issue.

Assume an AWS S3 bucket contains an unknown number of files. I have already written operators that are capable of performing the tasks I need on an individual file, and my goal is to parallelize the process. Ideally, I want an operator that inherits from `SubDagOperator` and accomplishes something similar to the following:

```
def fn_generate_operator_for_s3_file(s3_file):
  task_id = unique_task_id_for_s3_file(s3_file)
  return MyS3FileActionOperator(task_id=task_id, s3_file=s3_file)

AwsS3BucketMapOperator(SubDagOperator):
  def __init__(aws_s3_bucket_config, fn_generate_operator_for_s3_file, **kwargs):
    # Disregard implementation, just know that it retrieves the bucket
    aws_s3_bucket = get_aws_s3_bucket(aws_s3_bucket_config) 

    with DAG(subdag_name, ....) as subdag:
      for s3_file in aws_s3_bucket:
        operator_task = fn_generate_operator_for_s3_file(s3_file)
        # operator_task should be added to subdag implicitly due to the `with` context manager statement

    super(AwsS3BucketMapOperator, self).__init__(subdag=subdag, **kwargs)
```

In essence, I want to be able to map an arbitrary operator that is known to be able to handle an S3 file across all files (or some filtered set of files) in an S3 bucket, using some operator_generator callable that is passed to the Map Operator in order to actually instantiate the subdag operators.

Caveats: My understanding of how DAGs are discovered is that the `__init__` method of Operator instances in a DAG are all run prior to the actual execution phase of the DAG itself, and that it actually does this discovery process continuously.

There are cases where the process of actually gathering the configuration needed to accurately determine what set of subdag Operators need to be generated is computationally expensive.

Ideally I'd like to have the generation process of the subdag only be run once, and the only way I could see that is if the generation of the subdag occurs in the `execute()` method of the Map Operator class. Doing this however results in a situation where the subdag is not found in the DagBag, and thus fails to run. Is there any way around this?

If there is no way to programmatically determine the contents of the subdag at execution time, are there ways to limit how often the expensive operations needed to generate the subdag are run?